# Post as a reply/response to a previous post in Facebook Workplace

Tags: facebook-workplace

If I do the following request:
[image]
I get an ID back in the format: groupid_postid
This is taken from here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/reference/graph-api/post. However, there doesn't appear to be any way of posting as a reply to a post. I decided to try and intuitively come up with routes into it:
[image]
and many more but I'm just making it up at this point. Anyone have any idea how to post a message as a reply to that post id you get back? It's possible within the workplace itself:
[image]
so I had assumed it was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post a comment under another comment using the following API:

POST [https://graph.workplace.com/{post-id}/comments](https://graph.workplace.com/%7Bpost-id%7D/comments)

with a body like so:

```
{
    "message": "Comment on article post"
}
```

Note:

- The ID shouldn't be the group-id_post-id. It should just be the post-id.